# Is there something like git reset except using git merge or something else without rebasing?

Tags: git

I pushed a whole bunch of stuff to a `stage` branch.

Now I want to make it exactly like the `master` branch, but I can't rebase/force push.

I know there's `git merge -X theirs branch`, but I completely want to discard any changes in the `stage` branch and make it look exactly like the `master` branch.

Is there an easy way to do that with git?

Diagram:

```
 common
ancestor---stuff i don't care about---stage (A)
       \
        \________master (B)
```

Comment: If you don't want to preserve the history of A, you could delete and recreate it `git checkout B`, `git branch -D A`, `git checkout -b A`

Comment: This question would benefit enormously from a little bit of ASCII art showing some commits before / after...

Comment: Thanks @DietrichEpp I updated it with an ASCII diagram.  In a previous incarnation of the question, branch A referred to stage and B referred to master.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is: `git reset`.

```
git checkout B~0
git reset --soft A
git commit
git checkout -B A
```

The first command sets up your working tree and index to match B, without putting you on any branch ("detached HEAD"). The point of this is that the next commands do not mess up your branches.

The second command sets up `A`'s commit as the "current" commit that will be used as the parent for `git commit`, while leaving your working tree and index unmodified.

The third command creates a commit. Its parent will be the last commit of `A`, and its effect will be to set the tree exactly as `B` has it.

The fourth command puts you back on a branch. It updates the `A` branch to your newly created commit.

Comment: Just `git reset --hard A` ?

Comment: Why not? It's exactly what OP wants: *I completely want to discard any changes in branch A and make it look exactly like branch B*. Ah, branch `B` should be.

Comment: @0andriy Just `git checkout A`, `git reset --hard B` would nuke `A`'s history, which would then require a force push to get it on the server. The OP can't force push.

Comment: In the question I see nothing about keeping the history. So, I would extend your answer with `--hard` option as well.

Comment: @0andriy From the question: "but I can't rebase/force push" That is what requires keeping the history.

Comment: Ah, okay, fair enough.

Comment: Ooh, I like the trick with `B~0`.  I've never seen that befor.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Heh, probably because the normal way to do this is `git checkout --detach B`. I'm not sure what situation I was originally in that I used that frequently enough to look for a way to save on typing, but whatever it was, it had become a habit for me afterwards.

Comment: duh, nice one!  should have thought of it starting from branch B (i.e. master) first!